# I have created an ASP.NET Core Web API with Visual Studio but the front-end is in Angular. How can I configure it?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-webapi

The problem is how I can configure the Angular application while my backend work which is an ASP.NET Core Web API, created in Visual Studio and the frontend is Angular created in Visual Studio Code and just want to run the application but don't know how.

Comment: You can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 0):

'dotnet run' should work. This launches the ASP.NET Core app and it ng serve's Angular. It runs on port 5000 as default (Kestrel).
Or use IIS/IIS Express when using VS as an IDE instead.

Also, you may run into a timeoutException. This is a known bug when using Angular with ASP.NET Core. [There is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62087907/13929739)

Edit: You need to use [SpaServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0#:%7E:text=SpaServices%20was%20created%20to%20position,Server%2Dside%20prerendering) for this. There are templates for this when creating a new project.

Comment: The SPA templates for ASP.NET Core is going away soon. Check what Visual Studio 2022 offers, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2022?view=vs-2022

Comment: @LexLi Thanks, I didn't know this. Very valueable information! I really needed to know this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link both front end and back end using `HttpClient` module in angular.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and in service file you need to specify the path for respective http requests which will call the backend code in Web API.

Answer (score 0):

Okay at last what i did is inside angular.json file and under production configuration added "outputPath": "dist/wwwroot" and guess what ? It did my work